# Gx15 U4 NetWeb- Error CS0103: The name 'elink' does not exist in the current context

Tags: genexus

Este error me ocurre luego de especificar la opción de encriptar parámetros utilizando SessionKey.

Realicé varios Rebuild como menciona el SAC #38176 pero no tuvo efecto.

¿Se les ocurre algún otro work around?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta esto: configura para no especificar y generar concurrentemente. Luego cierra y abre GeneXus. Elimina *.ari de la KB. Haz rebuild all 2 veces.

Comment: Probé, no funcionó...

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné.

El problema se da solo en webcomponents generados por algunos patterns. Como no los utilizaba, los eliminé y ahora pude hacer el buildall sin problemas.